# Information added as comments, should I edit the question?

Tags: support, comments, editing

If a question seems incomplete, I would ask for additional information in a comment.  If the answer comes as a comment as well, we end up with lots of comments with valuable information.

Is it important to keep the history of comments, or should I edit the question to add the additional information?

But then, should I flag the comments to be deleted to keep everything clean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I'd suggest adding any requested details to the question, and then flagging the comments for deletion.